# what is the main differences between the capacitors?

Tags: capacitor, decoupling-capacitor, bypass-capacitor, smoothing-capacitor

I have read many documents on these terminologies. I find almost same working for these capacitors.
Please make me clear what is the main difference between bypass capacitor, decoupling capacitor & smoothing capacitor?

Thanks

Comment: You need to do your own research on this instead of asking us to write an article for you. There are thousands of articles on the web on this subject. Come back when you have a specific question.

Comment: I have also mentioned that I have read many documents for understanding the theoretical concepts. I was in bit dilemma of the differences. I wanted to ask the main differences from the experts in this forum from their personal experience rather than theoretical concepts so that It can make me more clear about the things for my further research. Maybe I have asked some silly question, won't ask again these kinds of questions.

Comment: Improve your question then. Edit it to explain what you *do* understand by the terms (using examples of where they are used) and ask if your understanding is correct. This will reduce the amount of work required to answer and the answers will address your particular confusion. You may even find that in doing this some of the answers become apparent as you type out the questions.

Comment: +1 for *Edit it to explain what you do understand by the terms (using examples of where they are used) and ask if your understanding is correct.*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

They are all capacitors with different usage. I'll give you some of my own experience.

Simply, bypass capacitor is used to bypass AC signal, since only AC voltage can go through a capacitor.

Decoupling capacitor is typically used between two electrical components, in order to bring up the signal to a certain level(in a complicate circuits, not all the devices will get the AC transition fast or accurate enough.)

smoothing capacitor is normally used in a power supply when converting AC to DC.

My answer may not be 100% right. But there are plenty of articles talking about these capacitors, you can easily look up online, google is your best friend.

Comment: whoever down voted me, i would like to know why, if anything wrong with my answer please let me know, I am very appreciate it. If you just simply don't like it. That's fine then.